# collapsed div with overflow hidden

Tags: html, css

I want to understand why the elements of my first div has not been shown on my page.

Take a look at the code: http://jsfiddle.net/ny48t/1/

The div MenuAreaLogada is collapsed. I learned the I should put overflow: hidden in div that has no content. I put it but it doesn't work.

I want to have my page divided in two divs: one at top and the other bellow the first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not giving it any height and using position absolute for it's children.

http://jsfiddle.net/ny48t/2/

Comment: Ok. thank you. I removed the absolute position of the child and It works well.

Comment: If I want to keep a text on bottom, It's mandatory to use absolute?